# XtraReport and xrTable shows only 1 record

Tags: reporting, devexpress

I have a linq to sql generated object MyObject and this contains an EntitySet.
Now i use an XtraReport with a BindingSource.DataSource = MyObject. I have a xrTable in the Detail band (which is the only one i use btw) with four xrTableCells binded binded to properties from MyObject.MyotherObject.Property. It keeps showing me only the first record and not all of them.

Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to implement the ITypedList with your custom object to use it as a datasource. Check out this online documentation article for more info:

http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraReports/CustomDocument4046.htm

Comment: I use LINQ to SQL generated Objects. And as i can see this would cause me lots of problems, i should crate my own collection and change my generated objects, this would be bad.I didn't knew this would be such a noise for a Table.

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved a similar problem. Did you use typed datasets to help you layout the report at design time? If you did then clear the Data Source in design view. If you apply LINQ to SQL Data Source at runtime without clearing the typed dataset Data Source in the design view, you may get only one row showing in  the detail band.

Answer (score 1):

i have similar problem and tried above answers, but it was so simple 
just set your report DataMember to the name of your sub collection MyObject.MyotherObject
and the table will load all items in your sub collection.

```
XtraReport report = new XtraReport(){DataSource = MyObject,DataMember="MyotherObject" };
```